# Can't get info with web3: web3.eth.getAccounts returns undefined

Tags: web3js, metamask, react, frontend, typescript

I'm trying to connect to the blockchain via web3 and metamask and the `web3.eth.getAccounts()` method is returning **`undefined`**, however `window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' })` returns an array with the accounts.

This is my code:

```
const getWeb3 = () : Promise<Web3> =>
  new Promise<Web3>((resolve, reject) => {
    // Wait for loading completion to avoid race conditions with web3 injection timing.
    window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
      // Modern dapp browsers...
      if (window.ethereum) {
        const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        
        try {
          // Request account access if needed
            const test = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
            console.log(test)// ["0x3b6f82ad02bf6820fe7062ae08817f54467bfb2a"]
         
          const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
          console.log(accounts) // undefined

          resolve(web3);
        } catch (error) {
          reject("User denied account access. " + error);
          console.log("User denied account access. " + error)
        }
      }
      // Legacy dapp browsers...
      else if (window.web3) {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider.
        const web3 = window.web3;
        console.log("Injected web3 detected.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
      // Fallback to localhost; use dev console port by default...
      else {
        const provider = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(
          "http://127.0.0.1:8545"
        );
        const web3 = new Web3(provider);
        console.log("No web3 instance injected, using Local web3.");
        resolve(web3);
      }
    });
  });
```

I need to use resolved web3 in another file, but right now everything that I try to access is returning undefined, for example, `await web3.eth.net.getId();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up solving this error by changing the version of **web3**, I was in version *0.20.x*, and I changed it to the latest version, which was 1.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use**
`web3.eth.getAccounts()`
This has been deprecated. It may still be supported within the library for the legacy type of dapp browsers & wallets but it is recommended to use the new web3 method below.

The new version of Web3 recommends to use
`web3.eth.requestAccounts()`

---

**Where you have declared**

```
const test = await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' });
```

This is not a web3 method and while it could be used to load your dapp with the user's accounts, it may not work on all dapp browsers & wallets, especially older ones.

---

The last statement of yours about the undefined
`web3.eth.net.getId()`
This is incorrect. `net` is separate from `eth`
Try `web3.net.getId()` instead.

---

Also, if the function needs to query the blockchain for data, the function should be asynchronous or used with callbacks.

***Hope this helps some!***

- ***@hashguide***